# $\det(I-A)=\sum_k (-1)^k \operatorname{tr}(\wedge^k A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, representation-theory, multilinear-algebra

I have an equality which I am struggling to grasp: in an article the author says that
$$
\det(I-A)=\sum_k (-1)^k \operatorname{tr}(\wedge^k A),
$$
where $\wedge^k A$ is the map induced by $A$ on the $k$-th degree of the alternating algebra $\bigwedge^{\!*} V$. ($V$ has finite dimension, so the summands definitively vanish).

I wanted to ask if there is a representation of $\wedge^k A$, and how I can prove the equality. I want to apologize in advance, I know that it has to be some simple multilinear algebra stuff, but I don't really know much about it (not even a good reference book, which would be greatly appreciated).

I want to thank in advance everybody who will answer this.

Comment: This post might help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630815/cayley-hamilton-theorem-trace-of-exterior-power-form The OP there made a follow-up question in an attempt to prove the formula you are interested in. You may be able to extract a proof from that.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps, to simplify computations, you can do them in the algebraic closure of the given field, using Jordan normal form.

Comment: It's maybe a little easier to first prove $$\det(A+I)=\sum_k\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}(\wedge^k A)$$ to avoid dealing with one set of sign factors, then substitute $-A$ for $A$. One way of proving the latter is by applying Cauchy-Binet to the product of the block matrices $[A I]$ and $[I I]^T$.

Answer (score 2):

Work over an algebraically closed field, so $A$ has generalized eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$. Then the generalized eigenvalues of $\wedge^kA$ are of the form $\lambda_{i_1}\cdots\lambda_{i_k}$ where $1\le i_1<\cdots<i_k\le n$. Now the equality is simply the classical identity
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\lambda_i)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_k}\lambda_{i_1}\cdots\lambda_{i_k}.$$